# How do you diagonalize this matrix and find P and D such that A = PDP^-1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

[image: question]

```
 1   1   4
 0  -4   0
-5  -1  -8
```

I<sub>3</sub> = 3x3 identity matrix

```
             λ   0   0
λI3  =       0   λ   0
             0   0   λ


    λ-1     -1      -4
=   0        λ+4     0
    5        1       λ+8
```

Rule of Sarrus to find determinant:

```
λ–1     -1      -4       λ–1    -1      
0       λ+4      0       0       λ+4
5       1        λ+8     5       1
```

Eigenvalues:
λ = -3, λ = -4

Eigenvectors:

for λ = -3:

```
-1
 0
 1
```

for λ = -4:

```
 4
 0
-5
```

The thing is, when I put this in any online matrix calculator, it comes up with different eigenvectors.

```
       -4   0   0
D   =   0  -4   0
        0   0  -3
```

I am not coming up with any of the multiple choice answers, but I know it has to be one of them.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what multiplicity of an eigenvalue is? Is it always 1?

Comment: Test-taking strategy: Work backwards.  If you're given options for $P$ and $D$, try multiplying $PDP^{-1}$.  It's quite easy to invert a matrix, it's a little more difficult to find eigenvectors.  (Note: you should still learn how to do this problem, obviously--this is just in case you're on a test and pressured for time.)

Comment: Note that similar matrices have the same [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29). Therefore it cannot be A. And you also know that, if there exists a diagonal matrix, then the sum of diagonal elements must be $-11$ and only numbers $-4$ and $-3$ are allowed on diagonal. (In B and C you are given matrices which are not diagonal. So if you know that one of the possibilities A, B, C, D must be correct, only D remains. Given the wording of the question, I would expect also E: There do not exist such P and D.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve $(A+4I)x=0$ by reducing the augmented matrix, you obtain
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1/5&4/5&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Letting $y=5s$ and $z=5t$ gives $x=-s-4t$, so

the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\5\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-4\\0\\5\end{bmatrix}$ are eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=-4$.

Therefore we could take these vectors as two columns of $P$; but since

the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-9\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\-4\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are linear combinations of these vectors,  we can use them as the columns corresponding to $\lambda=-4$ instead.

Therefore C) is correct.

---

A quicker way to work this problem is to find the eigenvalues $\lambda=-3$ and $\lambda=-4$,

conclude that C) is the only possible correct answer,

and then check to see if $Av_1=-4v_1$, $Av_2=-4v_2$, and $Av_3=-3v_3$ where

$P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 &|&v_2&|&v_3\end{bmatrix}$.